# Vector Method Java

Tags: java, vector

I am trying to create a vector method called readfromfile which would potentially read the input from a different text file. Why does it give an error?
Edit: Thanks for the help, I have edited the code and it works! 
Looks like I was confusing parameters and methods! :P
Thanks guys :D

```
    package cas.lab1.firsteclipsePackage;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class FirstEclipseClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Vector input = new Vector();    
            input.add("A");
            input.add("B");
            input.add("C");
            input.add("D");
            printVectorElements(input, 3);
            Vector<String> results = readFromFile();
        }


        public static void printVectorElements(Vector input, int count) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                System.out.println(input.get(i));

            }   
        }
        public static Vector<String> readFromFile(){ //yeah I did confuse methods and parameters
            Vector<String> result = new Vector<String>();
            try{
            File f = new File("input.txt");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
            while(s.hasNextLine()) {
            int i = s.nextInt();
            if(i % 2 == 0)
            result.add("Even");
            else
            result.add("Odd");
            System.out.println(i);
            }
            s.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you receive an error and ask a question about it, *always* include the error in the question. (I'd also recommend that you use `List<T>` instead of `Vector<T>`, and use `ArrayList<T>` as your "default" implementation.)

Comment: You're confusing the method parameter with the method return-type.

Comment: `public static Vector<String> readFromFile(){` missing return type.

Comment: You should fix the indentation of the content of the `readFromFile` method.

Comment: Yeah u r right! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are confused here. From your method call, I see that you don't need to pass any parameters, and instead want a Vector back. So I suggest you to change this line:

```
public static readFromFile(Vector<String> results){
```

To this line:

```
public static Vector<String> readFromFile(){
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing: you didn't specified the return type. You should have :

```
public static Vector<String> readFromFile()
```

if you do not need any parameters in the function.

Second, for future, you cannot have this same name in the function and as a function parameter

Comment: Read the question care fully whether its static or instance method, contains params or not.